# chrome modify headers in selenium java, i am able to add extension .crx through script

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am able to add extension(.crx ) through selenium web driver

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addExtensions(new File("src/main/resources/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj.crx"));
```

But unable to add name and value through selenium java. can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome stores the settings of an extension in the localstorage. So one way to customize your extension is to first set the context on it and then edit the localstorage with a piece of Javascript.

Here is an example adding two headers (token1 and token2) to ModHeader:

```java
// add the ModHeader extension
ChromeOptions  options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("C:\\Downloads\\ModHeader_v2.0.9.crx"));

// launch the browser
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// set the context on the extension so the localStorage can be accessed
driver.get("chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/icon.png");

// setup ModHeader with two headers (token1 and token2)
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{                " +
    "  title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '',           " +
    "  headers: [                                                      " +
    "    {enabled: true, name: 'token1', value: '01234', comment: ''}, " +
    "    {enabled: true, name: 'token2', value: '56789', comment: ''}  " +
    "  ],                                                              " +
    "  respHeaders: [],                                                " +
    "  filters: []                                                     " +
    "}]));                                                             " );

// visit a page
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. the above code worked, the only change that i made   was  ""chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/settings.tmpl.html" to access the local storage , the above link is redirecting to image page

Answer (score 0):

Download 2.1.2-Crx4Chrome.com.crx and try this below code

```
String userAgent = PropertyReader.readItem("USER-AGENT");
String xmsisdn = PropertyReader.readItem("X-MSISDN");
String xUPSUBNO = PropertyReader.readItem("xUPSUBNO");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File(PropertyReader.readItem("CHROMEEXT")));

options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Path\\chromedriver.exe");

//Launch the Browser 

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options); 

// set the context on the extension so the localStorage can be accessed 

webDriver.get("chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/icon.png");

// setup ModHeader with name and value
JavascriptExecutor js;
((JavascriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript(
"localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{                " +
"  title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '',           " +
"  headers: [                                                      " +
"    {enabled: true, name: 'User-Agent', value: '"+userAgent+"', comment: ''}, " +
"    {enabled: true, name: 'X-UP-SUBNO', value: '"+xUPSUBNO+"', comment: ''}  " +
"  ],                                                              " +
"  respHeaders: [],                                                " +
"  filters: []                                                     " +
"}]));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is to replicate user behavior

**Open extension option page and fill details you want to fill in.**

```
driver.get("chrome-extension://innpjfdalfhpcoinfnehdnbkglpmogdi/options.html")
by_id("btn_start")
by_id("btn_add_new")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('action_1'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Add')
send_by_name('name','name')
send_by_name('value','value')
by_id("btn_save_1")
by_id("btn_enable_1")
```

**Open your desired url now.**

```
driver.get("http://google.com")
```